# Xpath locator unable to detect the element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select a button using selenium however i believe i am doing something wrong while writing my xpath can anyone please help me on this i need to select the currency Euro.
link :- https://www.booking.com/

Locator which i want to select

[image]

Locator which i have written

[image]

```
USD = self.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[contains(text(),'selected_currency='Euro']")
USD.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below **xpath**

```
//a[contains(@href,'EUR') and starts-with(@class,'bui-list')]
```

is present two times in HTML DOM.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

In case you would like to select the first one which is in Suggest for you, there is no need to do anything with respect to XPath.

@pmadhu answer is misleading, since why would anyone look for first index in XPath when using with Selenium ? If there are multiple matching node, Selenium is always going to pick up the first element, So it really does not make any sense to me that why would someone use `[1]`

Nevertheless,

**to click on  Suggest for you EURO :**

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'EUR') and starts-with(@class,'bui-list')]"))).click()
except:
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In case you are looking to click on second matching node for EUR,

in that case it make sense to use index 2.

**XPath** would look something like this :

```
(//a[contains(@href,'EUR') and starts-with(@class,'bui-list')])[2]
```

Comment: Thankyou @cruisepandey for explaining this so well however the second code which you mentioned does not work
(//a[contains(@href,'EUR') and starts-with(@class,'bui-list')])[2]

Answer (score 0):

The text you are looking for: `selected_currency='EUR'` is in the `data-modal-header-async-url-param` parameter of the `a` tag. You should run the `contains` on that.

Edit:
Locator: `//a[contains(@data-modal-header-async-url-param, 'selected_currency=EUR')]`

Comment: I did not get that can you please write the locator over here if possible

Comment: It is there now

Answer (score 0):

As already explained, `selected_currency=EUR` is in the attribute - `data-modal-header-async-url-param`.

However you can select the required option, with below code.

The xpath for the **EUR** option can be - `//div[contains(text(),'EUR')]`. Since it highlights 2 elements in the DOM using this xpath- `(//div[contains(text(),'EUR')])[1]`. Its important to find unique locators. [Link to refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

```
# Imports required for Explicit wait
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.get("https://www.booking.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Click on Choose currency option
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='bui-button__text']/span[contains(text(),'INR')]"))).click()

# Click on the EUR option.
euro_option = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//div[contains(text(),'EUR')])[1]")))
euro_option.click()
```